# Result of query of instructor id =1 is wrong or true

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, relationship, erd, entity-relationship

**Problem**

**How to get schedule for instructor from table CourseClass by SQL query?**

Course table has relation with Instructor table many to many and generated Instructor Course table.

Course table has relation with Class table many to many and generated CourseClass table.
and my diagram as following:

[ERD database design digram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JBPo.jpg)

**what i try is**

```
SELECT     dbo.Class.*, dbo.Course_Class.*, dbo.Course.*, dbo.Inst_Course.*, dbo.Instructor.*
FROM         dbo.Class INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Course_Class ON dbo.Class.ClassID = dbo.Course_Class.ClassID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Course ON dbo.Course_Class.CourseID = dbo.Course.CourseID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Inst_Course ON dbo.Course.CourseID = dbo.Inst_Course.CourseID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Instructor ON dbo.Inst_Course.InstID = dbo.Instructor.InstructorID
WHERE     (dbo.Inst_Course.InstID = 1)
```

**I get 4 rows as result of query i see it is wrong it must be 2 rows . 
Are my result is wrong or true ?**

[Result of query is wrong or true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTZhO.jpg)

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? What two rows do you think it should be? Please read the answers I posted to your other recent questions about this design. PS Re SO questions: Please put information into your question, not in links. You can type the schema corresponding to an ER diagram. You can run it at sqlfiddle.com and paste the input and output into your question. Read about [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your results are correct. 1) there aren't any duplicate rows in your results. 2) You can double check this by looking at your source tables. There are 2 Course IDs for instructor 1 in Inst_Course (1 and 2) which correspond to 4 rows in Course_Class (see CourseID column, there are 3 "1" time slots and 1 "2" time slots).